# Problems using I2C from Raspberry Pi to Arduino with Python

Tags: python, arduino, raspberry-pi, kivy, i2c

So I have a GUI that is supposed to read some values from an SQLite database and write them over I2C to an arduino every second. It works great for 10 or so writes but then I get an I/O error printed to the raspi as if the connection changed. Am I throwing too much data over I2C? Overloading it? Or is something else happening? Or is the arduino not grabbing the data correctly? I don't have a good grasp of python or I2C, so if there's a better way to accomplish my goals please let me know.

Error is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "GUI.py", line 789, in <module>
     MainApp().run()
   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/kivy/app.py", line 828, in run
     runTouchApp()
   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/kivy/base.py", line
487, in runTouchApp
     EventLoop.window.mainloop()
   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/kivy/core/window/window_egl_rpi.py",
line 90, in mainloop
     self._mainloop()
   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/kivy/core/window/window_egl_rpi.py",
line 85, in _mainloop
     EventLoop.idle()
   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/kivy/base.py", line 327, in idle
     Clock.tick()
   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/kivy/clock.py", line
581, in tick
     self._process_events()
   File "kivy/_clock.pyx", line 368, in
kivy._clock.CyClockBase._process_events (kivy/_clock.c:7392)
   File "kivy/_clock.pyx", line 398, in
kivy._clock.CyClockBase._process_events (kivy/_clock.c:7269)
   File "kivy/_clock.pyx", line 396, in
kivy._clock.CyClockBase._process_events (kivy/_clock.c:7190)
   File "kivy/_clock.pyx", line 168, in kivy._clock.ClockEvent.tick
(kivy/_clock.c:3300)
   File "GUI.py", line 181, in update_labels
     self.i2cWrite("Beta4A " + beta4a)
   File "GUI.py", line 125, in i2cWrite
     bus.write_i2c_block_data(address, 0, StringToBytes(*args))
 IOError: [Errno 5] Input/output error
```

and again this happens after the code runs successfully 5 or so times, seems random how long until the error occurs

(Full code is here if you want https://github.com/ISS-Mimic/Mimic/blob/master/GUI.py) Here's the relevant part of the code:

```py
class MainApp(App):

    def build(self):
        self.mimic_screen = MimicScreen(name = 'mimic')
        root = ScreenManager(transition=WipeTransition())
        root.add_widget(MainScreen(name = 'main'))
        root.add_widget(CalibrateScreen(name = 'calibrate'))
        root.add_widget(self.mimic_screen)
        root.add_widget(ManualControlScreen(name = 'manualcontrol'))
        root.current= 'main'

        Clock.schedule_interval(self.update_labels, 1)
        return root

    def i2cWrite(self, *args):
        bus.write_i2c_block_data(address, 0, StringToBytes(*args))

    def update_labels(self, dt):
        global thatoneboolean
        c.execute('select two from telemetry')
        values = c.fetchall()

        psarj = str((values[0])[0])[:-5]
        ssarj = str((values[1])[0])[:-5]
        ptrrj = str((values[2])[0])[:-5]
        strrj = str((values[3])[0])[:-5]
        beta1b = str((values[4])[0])[:-5]
        beta1a = str((values[5])[0])[:-5]
        beta2b = str((values[6])[0])[:-5]
        beta2a = str((values[7])[0])[:-5]
        beta3b = str((values[8])[0])[:-5]
        beta3a = str((values[9])[0])[:-5]
        beta4b = str((values[10])[0])[:-5]
        beta4a = str((values[11])[0])[:-5]
        aos = str((values[12])[0])[:1]

        self.mimic_screen.ids.psarjvalue.text = psarj
        self.mimic_screen.ids.ssarjvalue.text = ssarj
        self.mimic_screen.ids.ptrrjvalue.text = ptrrj
        self.mimic_screen.ids.strrjvalue.text = strrj
        self.mimic_screen.ids.beta1bvalue.text = beta1b
        self.mimic_screen.ids.beta1avalue.text = beta1a
        self.mimic_screen.ids.beta2bvalue.text = beta2b
        self.mimic_screen.ids.beta2avalue.text = beta2a
        self.mimic_screen.ids.beta3bvalue.text = beta3b
        self.mimic_screen.ids.beta3avalue.text = beta3a
        self.mimic_screen.ids.beta4bvalue.text = beta4b
        self.mimic_screen.ids.beta4avalue.text = beta4a

        if aos == "1":
            self.mimic_screen.ids.aoslabel.color = 0,1,0
            self.mimic_screen.ids.aosvalue.color = 0,1,0
            self.mimic_screen.ids.aosvalue.text = "Signal Acquired!"
        else:
            self.mimic_screen.ids.aosvalue.text = "Signal Lost"
            self.mimic_screen.ids.aoslabel.color = 1,0,0
            self.mimic_screen.ids.aosvalue.color = 1,0,0

        if thatoneboolean == True:
            print "true"
            self.i2cWrite("PSARJ " + psarj)
            self.i2cWrite("SSARJ " + ssarj)
            self.i2cWrite("PTRRJ " + ptrrj)
            self.i2cWrite("STRRJ " + strrj)
            self.i2cWrite("Beta1B " + beta1b)
            self.i2cWrite("Beta1A " + beta1a)
            self.i2cWrite("Beta2B " + beta2b)
            self.i2cWrite("Beta2A " + beta2a)
            self.i2cWrite("Beta3B " + beta3b)
            self.i2cWrite("Beta3A " + beta3a)
            self.i2cWrite("Beta4B " + beta4b)
            self.i2cWrite("Beta4A " + beta4a)
            self.i2cWrite("AOS " + aos)
        else:
            print "false"
```

Here's the arduino side

```py
#include <Wire.h>
#include <Stepper.h>

void setup()
{
  Wire.begin(4);                // join i2c bus with address #4
  Wire.onReceive(receiveEvent); // register event
  Serial.begin(9600);           // start serial for output
}
void loop()
{
  delay(200);  
}
void receiveEvent(int howMany)
{
  String test = "";

  while(Wire.available()) // loop through all but the last
  {
    char c = Wire.read(); // receive byte as a character
    test += c;
  }
  Serial.println(test);
  int x = Wire.read();    // receive byte as an integer
  Serial.flush();
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Please edit the question to include the full (i.e. All of it) text of the error message including the line number where the error occurred, and indicate which of the lines above is that line.

Comment: Full error text added, line 125 is bus.write_i2c_block_data(address, 0, StringToBytes(*args))

Comment: Does it always fail on Beta4A? What is in beta4a when it fails? Any idea how much data you are in fact trying to send every second?

Comment: Serial data rate iseems slow compared to possible I2C data rate of 100khiz or so. If you change the serial data rate does the frequency of errors change? If you remove the serial.println do the errors disappear?

Comment: First question - no it does not always fail on beta4a (but it usually seems to be around there). Also sometimes it completes 5 full transmissions (all values sent) sometimes it errors after 70, with nothing changing - just added info. The typically data being sent is "Beta4a 207.5016" always the identifier followed by an 8 character number. Second question - okay yes I just removed all serial lines and the error still occurs

Comment: What do you mean: "nothing changing - just added info"? How much data are you sending (i.e. How long does the string test get)? If at Pi end in i2cwrite you print the length/contents of each string do they look sensible?

Comment: Oh sorry usual operation case for the code will have a javascript app updating the SQLite database and then the pi is fetching the values from that database and sending them to the arduino. I've been running it standalone without the database values changing, just to eliminate that variable. The length is always 15 characters for the Beta values and 14 for the SARJ/TRRJ values, and 6 for the AOS value. The printed contents all look exactly they should. And the arduino side printing them looks the same

Comment: 1) Any possibility of glitches - Is the connection between Pi and Arduino good - common ground, same power supply, plenty of current margin in the PSU? 2) in the pi, address is a (nasty) global, sure it is correct value (4)? Any other globals. (You could specify the address to the MainApp class when it is instantiated, and then use self.address - much less nasty)

Comment: 1) Check, all connections are good, PSU outputs 3A. 2) confirmed with i2cdetect 3/4) okay I just hardcoded the address for now, no more globals. Still getting the error. I should mention that I had this same problem when I was trying to get the javascript app to do the I2C stuff instead. Also when I reduce the data written to be just the first value (PSARJ) it has been error-free for the past 20 minutes, sooo I'm really suspecting it has something to do with the amount of data being written. Also thanks for the help